# Research ideas in Homological algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am planning to focus my research on Homological Algebra and related fields. I am on my first year, first semester and currently pursuing courses on Homological Algebra, Algebraic Geometry (first basic course studying Musili and Hartshorne).Algebraic Geometry is very new for me. Please suggest some references,so that I can come across and can learn current research areas in Commutative Algebra. Also I seek your suggestion in finding the area of interesting and full of lot of research problems in this field. As of now , I only started studying Algebraic geometry, but in Commutative Algebra I already studied the first book Atiyah Macdonald.

Sincere advance thanks for your help.

Comment: I've spoken to a few first-year students interested in homological algebra and it always struck me funny. Homological algebra is a tool, so you are doing well to study algebraic geometry (also algebraic topology, etc.) to find contexts where the tools are useful and where interesting problems arise. The commutative algebra book I've found most useful (besides A-M, which is a great reference for the basics) is Matsumura's older text, but that's practically impossible to find nowadays.

Comment: Thank you Sir, for your reply. So can you suggest me some journals of current research on Commutative Algebra, or applications of Homological Algebra. It will help me to get some direction to choose my final topic.

Comment: You could try looking at the [expository papers of Hochster](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/mse.html). I'm not seriously suggesting these are student projects but it might give you some idea of what's interesting to people in the field. There was a more recent [MSRI program](https://www.msri.org/programs/267) with videos you can watch as well. Again, this is probably not the way to go about finding a research topic but it's interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the references.